# Where exactly is Xcode told to build i386 & x86_64 for the simulator?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, xcode6, ios-frameworks

I cannot find anything in the build settings related to the simulator. How exactly does the architecture change to i386 and x86_64 when building for the simulator?

I'm trying to understand the build process so that I can create a fat binary Cocoa Touch Framework for iOS 8 for simulator and device that contains every architecture.

Comment: You don't see the build settings whose names contain the word "architecture"?

Comment: Those don't contain i386 or x86_64. There is nothing anywhere that references these architectures. How is it possibly building for the simulator?

Comment: "Those don't contain i386 or x86_64" But Xcode knows there is a simulator and it knows what architectures that simulator runs under. So `armv7` means "`i386` if we are building for a Simulator."

Comment: I created a fat binary as well. You have to explicitly specify i386 under "Valid Architectures", also make sure your build active architecture only is set to NO.

Comment: @Vig Are you able to submit apps to the store with the fat binary framework?

Comment: @Locutus I am not sure on that, I guess you should be able to. I don't see why you can't

Comment: @Vig It seems you can't anymore. But new libraries like Urban Airship still have fat binary dynamic frameworks. Fat static binaries will only link the corresponding architecture, but dynamic ones will still contain i386 & x86_64.